# Limit number of requests to a .netcore API controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I have an application where requests to a controller will take a while to process. The controller starts a thread per request and eventually returns some data to a database. I need to limit how many requests can be processed. So let's say our limit is 100, if the controller is already processing 100 requests, the 101st request will return 503 status till at least one request is completed.

I could use an application wide static counter to keep count of current processes but is there a better way to do this ?

EDIT:

The reason why the controller takes a while to respond is because the controller calls another API, which is a large database spanning several TB of geostationary data. Even if I could optimize this in theory, its not something I have control over. To make matters worse, the third party API simply times out if I have more than 10 concurrent requests. I am already dropping incoming requests to a servicebus queue. I just need a good way on my api controller to keep a global count of how many requests are coming in and returning 503 whenever it exceeds a set number of requests.

Comment: maybe thinking in a way to make the process not take so long to process? That way you wouldn't need a "hack" like this in the first place..

Comment: Do **not spawn threads** inside an ASP.NET (Core) application! You mess up with the thread management. If the request is CPU intensive, run it on the **request thread**. If it's I/O intensive (network, database, filesystem) use async/await. For everything else (long running cpu based tasks) use background worker (as separate application) and a message bus to communicate between

Answer (score 0):

The requests to the API controller should not be limited. An idea would be to take requests and store the list of processes that need completing (database, queue etc)

Then create something outside the web request that processes this work, this is where you can manage how many are processed at once using parallel processing/multi-threading etc. (using windows service /Worker Role / Hangfire etc)

Once processed, you could communicate back to the page via SignalR to then get the data required to display once processed, or show status.

The benefit of this is that you can always go back to the page or refresh and get some kind of status, without re-running the whole process.